# Nicht-physiologische Wundheilung in der Chirurgie?

Tags: word-usage

Warum heißt es in der Chirurgie immer "physiologische Wundheilung"? Gibt's eine andere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Physiologisch* bedeutet im medizinischen Sinn alles, was "normal" oder "durch normale Körperfunktionen" geschieht - Der Gegenbegriff dazu ist *pathologisch*, also alles, was in irgendeiner Form krankhaft oder "nicht normal" ist.

*Physiologisch* **kann** bisweilen auch bedeuten "muss nicht behandelt werden" oder "Pflaster drauf und gut". Ich denke, das ist hier nicht gemeint - Auch eine Wunde, die genäht oder geklammert werden musste, weil sie zu tief war, um "normal" abzuheilen, wird danach (hoffentlich) einem *physiologischen Wundheilungsprozess* unterliegen.

Der  *pathologische Wundheilungsverlauf* wird auftreten, wenn die Wunde sich weigert, zu verheilen, Entzündungen auftreten oder sich eine unangemessene Narbe oder Wucherungen bilden.

Answer (score 3):

In dem Wikipedia-Artikel [*Physiologie*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physiologie) findet sich die Erklärung, dass

> das Adjektiv physiologisch auch im Sinne von normal, beim gesunden Menschen auftretend, nicht krankhaft, verwendet wird.

Das Gegenteil dazu, also *unphysiologisch* oder *pathologisch* bezeichnet dementsprend

> eine Abweichung von den normalen, beim gesunden Lebewesen auftretenden oder wünschenswerten Lebensvorgängen.

Somit wäre die physiologische Wundheilung die normale, wünschenswerte Heilung einer Wunde. Falls die Wunde aber eben nicht wunschgemäß und unkompliziert heilt, dann wird sie pathologisch.

Comment: [Hier](https://www.aerzteblatt.de/archiv/29167/Wundheilung-und-Wundheilungsstoerungen-Moderne-Konzepte-zur-Pathophysiologie-und-Therapie) ist ein Artikel im Ärzteblatt, der die Phrase _pathologische Wundheilung_ verwendet.

Comment: Und hier ist ein Link zu einem Medizin(er)-Wörterbuch: [Physiologisch](https://flexikon.doccheck.com/de/Physiologisch)

Comment: @Takkat Und gleich mit einer Schote: Wer findet den Tippfhlr?

Comment: @tofro: genau aus diesem Gurnd kann man kein copy & paste machen ;)